# 3 groups in each column by using ifelse

Tags: r, inequality

I have a sequence called `tauseq`, and a data frame called `data`. I'd like to classify each column by comparing with one of the values in `tauseq`.

There are 3 groups in each column, and I wonder how to do it by using `ifelse`. The following are my inequalities:

1. `data$ed-ec> tauseq[1]`
2. `tauseq[1]=< data$ed-ec=< tauseq[1]`
3. `tauseq[1]> data$ed-ec`

Comment: By python? If so, by pandas?

Comment: I would like to use R, do you have any idea?